# How to add the bang character to functors?

Tags: julia, functor

By convention, we add a bang character `!` to any function name that mutates its arguments, so for the following code example, should we add a `!` to the functor name?

```
mutable struct Foo
    a::Int
end

(foo::Foo)(val) = foo.a = val

f = Foo(1)  # f.a = 1
f(10)       # f.a = 10
```

In short, is it possible to call the last line as `f!(10)`? I am just curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call here is just the same as the name of your variable. So if you want it to contain a `!`, you will have to name your variable `f!`:

```
julia> f! = Foo(1)  # f.a = 1
Foo(1)

julia> f!(4)
4
```

There is nothing magical about the `!` character, it's just part of the identifier. So you have to put the `!` *inside* the actual name, *exactly* like you do with functions.